# error code 0 in sqlite with phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            var db;

            //function will be called when device ready
            function onDeviceReady() {
            db = window.openDatabase("Dummy_DB", "1.0", "Just a Dummy DB", 200000); //will create database Dummy_DB or open it
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }

            //create table and insert some record
            function populateDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SoccerPlayer');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  SoccerPlayer (id integer primary key, Name text, Club text)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Alexandre Pato", "AC Milan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Van Persie", "Arsenal")');
            }

            //function will be called when an error occurred
            function errorCB(err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
            }

            //function will be called when process succeed
            function successCB() {
                alert("success!");
                db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }
            function queryDB(tx) {

                tx.executeSql('SELECT Name,Club FROM SoccerPlayer', [], querySuccess);
            }

            function querySuccess(tx, result) {
                $('#SoccerPlayerList').empty();
                $.each(result.rows, function (index) {
                    var row = result.rows.item(index);
                    $('#SoccerPlayerList').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">' + row['Name'] + '</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">Club ' + row['Club'] + '</p></a></li>');
                });

                $('#SoccerPlayerList').listview();
            }
        </script>
```

i have create example of store and retrive database using phonegap but first alert succes and then after thrown error 0 . please help me i am new in phonegap..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            var db;

            //function will be called when device ready
            function onDeviceReady() {
            db = window.openDatabase("Dummy_DB", "1.0", "Just a Dummy DB", 200000); //will create database Dummy_DB or open it
                db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }

            //create table and insert some record
            function populateDB(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SoccerPlayer');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  SoccerPlayer (id integer primary key, Name text, Club text)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Alexandre Pato", "AC Milan")');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Van Persie", "Arsenal")');
            }

            //function will be called when an error occurred
            function errorCB(err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
            }

            //function will be called when process succeed
            function successCB() {
                alert("success!");
                db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }
            function queryDB(tx) {

                tx.executeSql('SELECT Name,Club FROM SoccerPlayer', [], querySuccess);
            }

            function querySuccess(tx, result) {
                $('#SoccerPlayerList').empty();
                $.each(result.rows, function (index) {
                    var row = result.rows.item(index);
                    $('#SoccerPlayerList').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">' + row['Name'] + '</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">Club ' + row['Club'] + '</p></a></li>');
                });

                $('#SoccerPlayerList').listview();
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `Sqlite` - error code 0 -> ok.

Comment: yes ,sir error code 0

Comment: I have the same problem, Trying to find any answer!

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

function queryDB(tx) {

```
            tx.executeSql('SELECT Name,Club FROM SoccerPlayer', [], querySuccess,errorCB);
        }
```